# Drill down link is not clickable on jaspersoft mobile app

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver, drilldown

I have created Drill down functionality in iReport. I have created hyperlink for this functionlity. This is working absolutely fine in Web URL but while accessing same on Jasper Mobile app, the link is not clickable.

Is there any property to make link enabled on Jasper Mobile app. I am using 2.2 version of the application and Jasper server 5.6

Please provide any solution for this.

Comment: All I can say is give it as much detail as you can. The more detail you give, the more likely you will get a good answer

Comment: for an example, I have three countries for each country click, I am showing the relative states and their population in my next report. I have created a hyperlink and set the reportexecution parameter to _report variable. This link is redirecting and giving me the desired output in web url (localhost:8080/jasperserver). but while accessing my first report on Jasper mobile application (iOS) the links are not clickable so I am unable to drill down to my next report.